# installing web application with integrated pool

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3

I have a web application that I want to install on IIS7. I use wix 3.7 but i see it does not support integrated pool out of the box.Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it does...

```
<iis:WebAppPool Id="SomeAppPool" ManagedPipelineMode="Integrated" />
```